# Как вставить изображение в кнопку PyQt6

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer, pyqt6

У меня возникла проблема, в отображении инонок у кнопок после конвертации ui созданное в Qt Designer в код на Python PyQt6.
Как сделать так чтобы картинки начались отображаться?
Мой код на GitHub: https://github.com/stsln/hex_file_tools

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852147/5909792

Comment: Степан, а что с вашим предыдущим вопросом?

Comment: Предыдущий вопрос там ответ был для PyQt5. Думал в PyQt6 тоже самое будет, но оказалось не так. Лучше тогда использовать PyQt5?

Comment: Если ваш вопрос еще актуален, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Нет, это проблемы были в путях, где хранятся файлы. Можно ещё спросить почему отображение в qt designer и после конвертации из ui качество падает и всё увеличивается?

Comment: Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, , предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.